# How to determine which definition of 'contingent'?

Tags: meaning-in-context

This quote was revealed to exemplify [Definition 1](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/contingent?q=contingent), but working backwards, how would you determine the meaning of **contingent**? Even after seeing the context, I'm still vacillating between definitions 1 (not 1.1, the one above 1.1) and 3. Don't they  both look right?

> But, while personal biographies and group histories are mutually immanent, they are relationally irreducible. The same context may produce several different collective 'histories', differentiating as well as linking biographies through **contingent** specificities. In turn, articulating cultural practices of the subjects so constituted mark **contingent** collective 'histories' with variable new meanings.

[Source:](http://books.google.com/books?id=rKCHAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA117&lpg=PA117&dq=%22articulating+cultural+practices+of+the+subjects+so+constituted%22&source=bl&ots=Jb8oaRY6Sg&sig=_ZgJI6kt5BVmhM9QQVDpGxdY8Xo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=673IU-b7GtTk8AWpt4KYDQ&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&=%22articulating%20cultural%20practices%20of%20the%20subjects%20so%20constituted%22&f=false) PP 177, Cartographies of Diaspora: Contesting Identities, by Avtar Brah

Comment: Definition 3 says *"philosophy"*. I don't believe this source is philosophy.

Comment: @PeterShor definition 3 is: "True by virtue of the way things in fact are and not by logical necessity". A philosophical concept might appear outside of academic philosophical publications. That said I'm not sure this fits here.

Comment: @Peter: Apparently, [*the doctrine of **mutual immanence**, stated most generally, is the claim that "every item in the universe, including all the other actual entities, are constituents in the constitution of any one actual entity*](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=urQPKdts0J8C&pg=PA240&lpg=PA240&dq=mutually+immanent&source=bl&ots=kGyoGlNNxt&sig=8NalyYcFiq3B5r5cCn_w34-RAf0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=x8_PU_-6GIP27AbV6IGgCg&ved=0CDgQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=mutually%20immanent&f=false). Is this context *philosophy, metaphysics*, or *"serious" theoretical physics*? I dunno.

Comment: @PeterShor re: First comment. That's not the way to go about it in this case anyway :)

Comment: I can only see as possible in context the meaning listed at 3. as of use in philosophy and none other.

Comment: I think this is better suited to a philosophical discussion area than English (the meanings of these terms are contingent on the authors immanent intentions rather than the language this is discussed in).

Answer (score 1):

The two definitions (1 and 3) are actually very different: in a way, they may be closer to being antonyms than synonyms: *subject to change* vs *true*... However, this passage is indeed confusing, and as @Peter has commented the verb *mark* does not match the subject [of the last sentence], adding to the confusion.

For the first **contingent** instance, the phrase *true* specificities does not make a lot of sense; *subject-to-change* specificities, however, is perfectly logical given the context:

> The same context may produce several **different** collective 'histories'.

The second **contingent** instance also does not lend itself to definition 3: *true* collective histories? However, the *subject-to-change* definition does indeed make sense, given the

> **variable** new meanings

context.

Answer (score -1):

I find it helpful to break down the sentences into their logical elements.

> In turn, articulating cultural practices of the subjects so
>   constituted mark contingent collective ‘histories’ with variable new
>   meanings.

Statements:

A = "Articulating cultural practices of the subjects"

B = "Constituted mark contingent collective ‘histories’ with variable new meanings."

Elements contained in the statements:

X = "mark contingent collective ‘histories'"

Y = "variable new meanings"

If statement A is true then statement B is true

Therefore X = Y

Therefore the only definition that supports this statement is "Subject to chance."

The second example sentence associated with [the definition](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/contingent?q=contingent), provides a more complicated application of this approach.

> That the emotions have a history implies that subjects are
>   historically contingent and open to the possibility that they are
>   hence culturally determined.

Statements
A = "Emotions have a history."

B = "Subjects are historically contingent."

C = "Subjects are culturally determined.

Elements contained in the statements:

X = "subjects"

Y = "historically contingent"

Z = "culturally determined"

If statement A is true then statement b is true AND statement C is true

Therefore X = Y is True and X = Z is True

Therefore Y = Z

Once again, the only usage that supports this statement is the first defintion.

Comment: While this is a complicated sentence, I think it should be analyzed as (1) "In turn, articulating cultural practices of the subjects so constituted" (2) "mark contingent collective ‘histories’ with variable new meanings." (1) is the subject, and (2) is the predicate. The verb is *mark*, not *constituted*. With this analysis, unfortunately, the subject and the verb don't match in plurality. But in your analysis, the word *"so"* is missing, and the words following the verb make no sense to me.

Comment: -1 This seems to follow interpretation "by logical necessity" rather than "by virtue of the way things in fact are." Lol. **3.** at http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/contingent?q=contingent